# How long does it take to ride 1.4 km?

Tags: road-bike

I guess I'm an average cyclist. I ride my bike if walking takes too long. There's a subway 1.4 km from my house. Google maps says 4 min but I'm not sure. It's all flat. About how long would it take?

Comment: Oh and I meant subway the fast food place 

Comment: This is basic mathematics, not bicycling.

Comment: @Criggie Or simple empiricism. It would take four minutes to find out whether Google is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 minutes sounds about right. It depends, of course, on how fast you ride and whether you have any delays such as traffic lights or road crossings. For that short a distance, you'll probably spend more time getting ready to ride and locking up your bike at the <s>station</s> restaurant.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the fast food place lol

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your terrain is relatively flat:

Average cyclists will be 10-15 km/h, so that's 8.5 and 6 minutes.

I've walked past a grannie cyclist while out exercising my dog, so she would be doing under 6 km/h and at that speed would take 21 minutes to get to the station.

A fast road bike does 40 km/h and the pros can do 50-55 km/h sustained, so that's 2.1 minutes and 1.5 minutes respectively.

The world land speed record on a bike is well above 130 km/h and at that speed you'd be at the station in ~38 seconds.

The formula is

```
( Distance in km ) / ( Speed im km/h ) * 60
```

returning a time in minutes.   This assumes no stopping for lights or traffic or crossing.